# Can't draw on a bitmap

Tags: c#, controls, bitmap, devexpress, mouseevent

I'm using `PictureEdit` (DevExpress control) as a child of some form. And I'm trying to draw a pixel onto loaded image using `MouseEventArgs` coordinate properties.

```
private void PictureEditorOnMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        (this.pictureEditor.Image as Bitmap).SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, this.colorPicker.Color);                                    
    }
}
```

ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurs saying that `x` (or `y`) parameter passed to SetPixel method isn't positive && greater than a given bitmap's `Height` property.
I was thinking that I use coordinates bound by `bitmap.Width` and `bitmap.Height`.

How do I bind them? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: When you debug, what values do e.X and e.Y have? Are they in the range of the bitmap?

Comment: why are you testing for button in mouse move?

Comment: ok, I can see what you are doing now. Once you get this working you'll find that users will draw freehand lines with gaps in because you won't get a mouse move message for every pixel between two points.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken you need to translate the coordinates. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void PictureEditorOnMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        PictureEdit pce = sender as PictureEdit;
        Bitmap bmpImage = pce.Image as Bitmap;
        PictureEditViewInfo viewInfo = pce.GetViewInfo() as PictureEditViewInfo;

        var p = new Point(
            (e.Location.X - viewInfo.PictureStartX) * bmpImage.Width / viewInfo.PictureRect.Width,
            (e.Location.Y - viewInfo.PictureStartY) * bmpImage.Height / viewInfo.PictureRect.Height);

        if (p.X >= 0 && p.X < bmpImage.Width && p.Y >= 0 && p.Y < bmpImage.Height)
        {
            bmpImage.SetPixel(p.X, p.Y, this.colorPicker.Color);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Out bounds");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to translate the mouse location into the aproximate pixel position of the Bitmap, taking into account the PictureEdit's SizeMode. This is done when the new point is created in the sample code.